# How can I filter products to show only those belonging to selected category in Django Admin?

Tags: django

I am trying to filter the options shown in a foreignkey field within Django Admin inline. Using formfield_for_foreignkey I'm able to show products with category_id = 4 but instead of the 4 I would like to filter based in the category field in the inline. Using kwargs["queryset"] = Product.objects.filter(category=F('order_line__category')) does not get the category field value.

```
class Order_lineInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Order_line

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "product":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Product.objects.filter(category=4)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)



    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Product(models.Model):
        part_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Order_line(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey('Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product  = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
Product.objects.filter(category__name='xxxxxx')
```

Comment: I'd like to set the filter automatically to the value chosen in the field category when entering the Order_line inline. Your solution is still using a constant, better than the 4 but still fixed.